# How to create Web Worker from script served from subdomain?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a website at `example.com` and I am serving all external resources from `cdn.example.com`. So in my HTML page at `example.com` I have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.example.com/script.js"></script>
```

In my script I want to create a Web Worker, so I do:

```
worker = new Worker("http://cdn.example.com/script.js");
```

But this fails on Firefox 16 with `Failed to load script: http://cdn.example.com/script.js (nsresult = 0x805303f4)` error. It works on Safari 6 and Chrome 22.

It seems the problem is because [origins differ](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#worker). Effective origin of the script is `example.com` and `cdn.example.com` does not match that. This seems a bug because not CORS not setting `document.domain` helps (or at least I couldn't make it to work by playing with that). Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Could [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy) help here?

Comment: Great idea. Tried. Buy sadly it does not work (no change). So the issue is only with Firefox.

Comment: I opened a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=806752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I made website at `example.com` serve a simple JavaScript code which includes the real web worked code:

```
importScripts('http://cdn.example.com/script.js');
```

and then create web worker by pointing to that.